# Why does nth-child equivalent work for css selector but not xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the xpath equivalent of this css_selector of this [website](https://www.tab.com.au/sports/betting/Soccer/competitions/English%20Premier%20League).

To get 6 elements I add: `div:nth-child(1)`.  For xpath it would be `//div[1]` yet this makes no difference. I am wanting all the 6 numbers under the left result [tab](https://ibb.co/htoZBb)

Css:

```
div:nth-child(1) > proposition-return > div > animate-odds-change > div > div
```

Returns 6 elements

xpath (quite similar):

```
//div[@class='propositions-wrapper'][1]//div[contains(@class, 'proposition-return')]//animate-odds-change//div//div
```

Returns 18

I desire 6.

```
<div ng-repeat="odd in odds" class="animate-odd ng-binding ng-scope" ng-class="{
  'no-animation': oddsShouldChangeWithoutAnimation

    }" style="">2.05</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are totally different selectors:

**CSS:** `div:nth-child(1) > proposition-return > div > animate-odds-change > div > div`

> Find every `div` that is the first child of its parent, then get its direct `proposition-return` child (I assume you wanted to use it like `.proposition-return`, then its direct `div` and so on..

**XPATH:** `//div[@class='propositions-wrapper'][1]//div[contains(@class, 'proposition-return')]//animate-odds-change//div//div`

> Find all `div` elements with `proposition-wrapper` as class, then only get the first. After, find all `div` with `proposition-return` class that are descendant of the previous element and so on..

`[1]` is very different to `nth-child(1)` to begin with, and also `//` is not the same as `>`, but `/` is.

For getting the specific elements that you want, I would use this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class, "template-item")]//div[@data-test-match-propositions]/div[1]//div[contains(@class, "animate-odd")]
```

Comment: I see.  Using [1] is as close as you can get to nth-child for xpath, correct?  For me the css displays 6,  and your xpath displays 18.  A different xpath that worked was rewrite entirely  here: //div[@class='propositions-wrapper'][1]/div[1]//div[@ng-repeat='odd in odds'][1]

Comment: @user9099 please check the updated answer with the xpath I would use.

Answer (score 0):

that site is not available worldwide, but looking at the img you provided helps.  as eLRuLL points out, your xpath is not equivalent to the css.

try getting rid of some of the double slashes

```
//div[@class='propositions-wrapper']//div[contains(@class, 'proposition-return')]/animate-odds-change/div/div[contains(@class, 'animate-odd')]
```

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where re-write was needed for desired :)